# Get id from ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to return `id` to the ajax success response. In my case a user selects a value from dropdown and as he selects,one input box gets populated with created date related to that selected option via AJAX response. I have another input box in which I input a number and submit it. This process has to update the selected option row in db. My issue is, when submitted it updates a different row or record. May I get some help over this. I will really appreciate the insights and will be too helpful.

```
<form  action=""  method="POST">

  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="username" class="control-label">
       <b>Online Batch No.</b>
    </label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <select style="width:200px" name="batchnumber" class="form-control"  id="batchno" required>   

      <option value=""><i>--Select a batch number--</i></option>                 
       <?php 
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT rpp_regn_batch_no, rpp_id FROM tbl_regn_prescribed_parameters where rpp_regn_batch_no  != 0");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){  
                 $rpp_id    = $row['rpp_id'];
                 $rpp_batch_no    = $row['rpp_regn_batch_no'] ;
             echo "<option value=" . $rpp_id . ">" . $rpp_batch_no . "</option>";     

           }
        ?>
      </select> <br>

 </div> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>Start Date:</b></label>            
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control" id="startdate" disabled value="">
   </div>
   </div> <br> <br>
 <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>Extension Days:</b></label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <input type="text" name="extdays" class="form-control"    value=""><br>
    <input type="button" name="id" id="text" value="<?php echo $rpp_id; ?>">
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' id='submit' name ='submit2'  class='btn btn-success glyphicon-floppy-disk' style="float: right;">

  </div></form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#batchno").change(function()
{
var id=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'rpp_id='+ id;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "batchno_details.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result)
{

$('#startdate').val(result);
}
});
});
});
</script>
   </div>
</div>   
</form>
```

**batchno_details.php**

```
<?php

session_start();


$db = new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);       


if($_POST['rpp_id'])
{
$start_id=$_POST['rpp_id'];
$sql="SELECT rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate FROM tbl_regn_prescribed_parameters WHERE  rpp_id='$start_id'"; 
$t= $db->query($sql);

if( $t === FALSE ) {
   trigger_error('Query failed returning error: '. mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
} else {


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($t))

{
$start_date=$row['rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate'];

$new_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($start_date) );

echo $new_date;
}
}   }
```

Comment: you should return a json object with the id and date, then you can assign the date as you currently are and perhaps update a data attribute on the batchno, which you could then use onchange.  I would probably rethink the way you are doing this though as someone may change that select before the id is assigned or if they are just changing but not selecting, you are going to get multiple calls to the db updating it which isn't great

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wanted to know how to use the json response on my submit button for 'id'

Comment: do you need to create element with id which included in json response?

Comment: Thanks it sorted. I used JSON array for the same.